# What does Islam say about homosexuality?

Tags: halal-haram, homosexuality

There are many difference of opinions in Islam about homosexuality. which one of these would be most correct?

- the first would be an extremist approach like in Islamic countries where they kill you if they find out you are homosexual
- the second is an opinionated response that they believe its haram and the person isn't a good Muslim and they must change to be straight.
- the third is one based on sins they believe are committed the belief that its natural and only committing adultery is haram
- the fourth is a complete denial that homosexuality is haram and when people believe the ayas in the Quran are only because the men were not married with the second group of men.

I personally believe its going to be either second or third mostly leaning on the third i used to completely believe in number three but recently many sheikhs have been convincing that its number 2 because of some ayas in the Quran that say that if there are women why would you be with men.

Answer (score 0):

according to Jafari Fiqh it has Hadd and he should be killed. but its killing has terms and fist should be proved and the fitwa of Hadd can be issued only by a qualified scholar Mujtahid).

also if a Muslim does not have any way unless immigration to keep his religion safe, he should immigrate.

ref:
http://makarem.ir/websites/english/estefta/

Quran says:

نَّ الَّذِينَ تَوَفَّاهُمُ الْمَلَائِكَةُ ظَالِمِي أَنفُسِهِمْ قَالُوا فِيمَ كُنتُمْ ۖ قَالُوا كُنَّا مُسْتَضْعَفِينَ فِي الْأَرْضِ ۚ قَالُوا أَلَمْ تَكُنْ أَرْضُ اللَّـهِ وَاسِعَةً فَتُهَاجِرُوا فِيهَا ۚ فَأُولَـٰئِكَ مَأْوَاهُمْ جَهَنَّمُ ۖ وَسَاءَتْ مَصِيرًا

[4:97] Sahih International
Indeed, those whom the angels take [in death] while wronging themselves - [the angels] will say, "In what [condition] were you?" They will say, "We were oppressed in the land." The angels will say, "Was not the earth of Allah spacious [enough] for you to emigrate therein?" For those, their refuge is Hell - and evil it is as a destination.

http://tanzil.net/#4:97