# What are the teachings of Islam about homosexuality?

Tags: homosexuality

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Islam and homosexuality](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/448/islam-and-homosexuality)

Is it okay for a human being to be gay, yet acceptable in the islamic world? Please answer in as much detail as possible with proper references to the sources.

Comment: Exact duplicate of [this](http://islam.stackexchange.com/q/448/167) and [this](http://islam.stackexchange.com/q/226/167).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Islamic views on homosexuality are formed from the writings of the Qur'an and various Hadith narrations. **It is not only a sin, but a crime under Islamic law.**

There are various quranic verses that say it is a sin and that the people are transgressing Allah's limits

#### In the Quran

> Indeed, you approach men with desire, instead of women. Rather, you are a transgressing people."  Qur'an (7:80)  Sahih International
>
> Do you approach males among the worlds
>   And leave what your Lord has created for you as mates? But you are a people transgressing." Qur'an (26:165-166) Sahih International
>
> And the two who commit it among you, dishonor them both. But if they repent and correct themselves, leave them alone. Indeed, Allah is ever Accepting of repentance and Merciful.  Qur'an (4:16)  Sahih International
>
> Do ye do what is shameful though ye see (its iniquity)? Would ye really approach men in your lusts rather than women? Nay, ye are a people (grossly) ignorant! Qur'an 27:54

#### From the Hadith:

> Narated By Abdullah ibn Abbas : The Prophet (peace be upon him) said: If you find anyone doing as Lot's people did, kill the one who does it, and the one to whom it is done. Abu Dawud 38:4447
>
> Narated By Abdullah ibn Abbas : If a man who is not married is seized committing sodomy, he will be stoned to death. Abu Dawud 38:4448
>
> Narrated AbuSa'id al-Khudri: The Prophet (peace be upon him) said: A man should not look at the private parts of another man, and a woman should not look at the private parts of another woman. A man should not lie with another man without wearing lower garment under one cover; and a woman should not be lie with another woman without wearing lower garment under one cover.  Abu Dawud 31:4007
>
> Narrated AbuHurayrah: The Prophet (peace be upon him) said: A man should not lie with another man and a woman should not lie with another woman without covering their private parts except a child or a father. He also mentioned a third thing which I forgot. Abu Dawud 31:4008
>
> AbuDawud said: From here I remembered this tradition from Mu'ammil and Musa: Beware! No man should lie with another man, no woman should lie with another woman except with one's child or father. He also mentioned a third which I have forgotten...  Abu Dawud 11:2169
>
> Whoever is found conducting himself in the manner of the people of Lot, kill the doer and the receiver.  Tirmidhi 1:152
>
> It was narrated by Jaabir (may Allah be pleased with him): "The Prophet (peace and blessings of Allah be upon him) said: 'There is nothing I fear for my ummah more than the deed of the people of Loot.'"  Tirmidhi 1457
>
> Malik related to me that he asked Ibn Shihab about someone who committed sodomy. Ibn Shihab said, "He is to be stoned, whether or not he is muhsan."  Al-Muwatta 41 41.111

#### According to various sects of Islam

(this part is taken from [wikiislam.net - Islam and Homosexuality](http://wikiislam.net/wiki/Islam_and_Homosexuality#Islam.27s_view_on_Homosexuality) )

In the case of homosexuality, how it is dealt with differs between the four mainline schools of Sunni jurisprudence today, but what they all agree upon is that homosexuality is worthy of a severe penalty.

In the Hanafi school of thought, the homosexual is first punished through harsh beating, and if he/she repeats the act, the death penalty is to be applied.

As for the Shafi school of thought, the homosexual receives the same punishment as adultery (if he/she is married) or fornication (if not married). This means, that if the homosexual is married, he/she is stoned to death, while if single, he/she is whipped 100 times. Hence, the Shafi`i compares the punishment applied in the case of homosexuality with that of adultery and fornication.

The Hanafi differentiates between the two acts because in homosexuality, anal sex [something that is prohibited, regardless of orientation] may also be involved, while in adultery [and fornication], the penis/vagina (which are reproductive parts) are involved.

Comment: Anal intercourse is probably no more common in gay than in straight relationships.