# Does the Koran condemn homophily or (the practise of) homosexuality?

Tags: sharia, quran, homosexuality

> So, first of all let me say I am not Muslim, nor am I here to condemn or judge any ideas, all I am looking for is some information.

Either way, I read [this question](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/226/what-does-the-quran-say-about-homosexuality) and I am not sure whether it means homosexuality itself **or** only the practice of homosexuality is condemned. To be more specific, I don't know whether the word *approach* in Arabic requires an active component, or whether the generic feeling whilst approaching would already count.

And as a slightly offtopic bonus (though I believe still technically on topic), if a distinction between the two is made, is this also the case in the implementation and understanding of the Koran in Muslim majority countries? (This was what the original discussion was about, whether people were executed for practicing homosexuality or for simply being homosexual)

Comment: It's the act of sodomy, cross-dressing, and whatever perverted acts it consists of.  Having "feeling" towards another man should be controlled.

Comment: @Sayyid Which would be the second option I presented, however is this the correct/only interpretation of the word approach? Or is this simply the perspective western culture defauts to?

Comment: That definitely is the second one. People get punished when they [perform it](http://islam.stackexchange.com/q/1734/9123). Being homosexual or not is beyond one's control, it's not a choice (in regards to biological development). See also, this [answer](http://islam.stackexchange.com/a/29855/9123)

Answer (score 1):

Ibn al-Qayyim said:

> "Both of them – fornication and homosexuality – involve immorality that goes against the wisdom of Allaah’s creation and commandment. For homosexuality involves innumerable evil and harms, and the one to whom it is done would be better off being killed than having this done to him, because after that he will become so evil and so corrupt that there can be no hope of his being reformed, and all good is lost for him, and he will no longer feel any shame before Allaah or before His creation. The semen of the one who did that to him will act as a poison on his body and soul. The scholars differed as to whether the one to whom it is done will ever enter Paradise. There are two opinions which I heard Shaykh al-Islam (may Allah have mercy on him) narrate.”

(al-Jawaab al-Kaafi, p. 115).

Allah says (interpretation of the meaning):

> And (remember) Loot (Lot), when he said to his people: "Do you commit the worst sin such as none preceding you has committed in the ‘Aalameen (mankind and jinn)?
>
> Verily, you practise your lusts on men instead of women. Nay, but you are a people transgressing beyond bounds (by committing great sins)”

[al-A’raaf 7:80-81]

The people of Lot(AS) were destroyed because they indulged in Homosexuality.

It is prohibited in Islam.

For entire article read: http://islamqa.info/en/10050

Comment: 'you **practise** your lusts' sounds like the practice is prohibited, not the state itself, how did you derive from that quote that homosexuality itself is prohibited?

Comment: 'Verily, you practise your lusts **on men instead of women**' It clearly saying 'Men instead of women '!!!

Comment: So... ... are you saying that homosexuality itself is not condemned, but only the practice of it?

Comment: Lol, please explain how it can be done? 

You mean, if a man is homosexual, he can be homosexual, but just not do anything...? is this what ur trying to say?

Comment: That is what the entire question is about...

Comment: **Allah doesn't punish you for what is in the Head! Allah punishes ones the thought is brought into action.** And according to Scholars, its unnatural for a human to be homosexual.

Comment: Now, I am fine with you believing this to be so, but could you please base this on actual sources? And/or by analyzing the arabic word from which *approach* is translated in the referenced verses in the OP?

Comment: Al-Bukhaari (5269) and Muslim (127) also narrated from Abu Hurayrah (may Allah be pleased with him), that the Prophet (blessings and peace of Allah be upon him) said: “Allah, may He be glorified and exalted, **will forgive my ummah for whatever crosses their minds so long as they do not act upon it or speak of it.**”

Comment: Al-Bukhaari (6491)&Muslim (131) narrated from Ibn ‘Abbaas that the Prophet(saw) said,“..Whoever thinks of doing a bad deed **then he does not do it**, Allah will write it down as one good deed, and if he thinks of it then does it, Allah will write it down as bad deed.”
so if a person doesn't DO the sin with his hand/mouth, even though he wants to, he is NOT accountable.

Comment: Put it all that together as an answer and I think you have a pretty good answer :D (One last personal question, so if in most muslim governed countries you would state "I am a homosexual, but I do not act upon it" how would they (re)act? If you do not know, then that's fine :) )

Comment: I don't know. But it would be good if you knew that most 'Muslim Governed countries' don't apply Islamic law. They only take some part of it.

Answer (score 0):

We must look at the essence of Islam. Islam is about submission to Allah and peace. I implore you to keep these two simple philosophies about Islam when pondering your question and reading my response.

Islam is all about having faith in things greater than this world. It treats the way we live in this world as a qualifier for the hereafter. Muslims are supposed to struggle and remain steadfast in their faith; not just to improve their position in the view of Allah but to live a life than doesn't cause them to become negative or thankless no matter how many challenges come their way. This struggle against evil and challenges thrown by this life are what defines a Muslim who is faithful and positive for others.

Herein lies the answers to your question. I say answers because there are two.

1. Homosexuality as in the act is definitely forbidden in Islam with various recollections of the fate of people who practiced such acts against the commandments of Allah. There are various verses in the Quran proclaiming the grave punishments dealt to the homosexuals and other people who practiced such acts such as the people of Prophet Luut. So yes, the act of homosexuality is most definitely forbidden in Islam.
2. Homosexuality as in the psychological or otherwise orientation of someone's sexuality is in my view most definitely not a sin. It is a challenge that a Muslim must face. Same as the challenges faced by people all over the world. Poverty, disease, terror or other afflictions that are thrown in the face of humanity are merely challenges they must stand up to and persevere. Homosexuality is another one of these challenges. Its definitely not easy I believe considering the statements of some of my friends. One must submit and fight it, one must pray and stay strong. Allah has his plans for everyone and ones that stay strong will surely be rewarded. And ones that do not, well who am I to judge? Allah will surely be merciful and I am sure some act of good they have done will come through for them.

I hope I have helped. I am merely going off some anecdotes and some experiences when talking to some gay and lesbian people that I do know. Perhaps I am right, perhaps I am wrong. I am most definitely not a perfect Muslim or Human. I am simply making a case for my belief in this matter and I hope it has helped!

Comment: You seem to be giving the answer based on generalized concepts instead of basing them directly on the Koran which I was trying to understand (and referenced) and which do not necessarily line up with your answer from my understanding (as in, specifically the word *approach*).

Comment: I may not have given specific verses from the Quran however I have alluded to them. And I am sure you must have done a search for these yourself considering your responses. The word approach in this instance would imply action, not just passive thought. In short if we have 'immoral' or 'evil' thoughts, we can choose to ignore them or we can choose to act on them. Our response to any thoughts is what will decide our fate