# What is the punishment for being gay or lesbian?

Tags: fiqh, punishment, homosexuality

With the knowledge of prohibition of gayness or lesbianism in Islam in mind, my question is: *What is the punishment put forward for gays and lesbians in Islam?*

Most of Prophet Lot's people (men, to be specific) were gay, yes, but they were also ***violent***. They would sexually harass any visitors of Prophet Lot's, as seen the way they tried to harass two visitors of his mentioned in the Quran  (the visitors were angels disguised as two handsome young men). Allah Subhanahu Wa Ta'ala later on punished them (the disbelieving people who continued this act) by raising the ground they were standing on, upended it, then pelted them with stones.

My point is that those men were not only gay, but also violent rapists. How about peaceful gay people who are just like regular people? One's that aren't violent to the human society? How does Sharia discuss the fate of such persons?

Comment: Maybe [What does Islam say about homosexuality?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/448/what-does-islam-say-about-homosexuality) is better.

Comment: There is no specific punishment sanctioned in the Quran.  The mission of Islam is not punishment but rather guidance, repentance, and forgiveness.  If Allah had so willed, he would have made mankind infallible like robotic super-beings.  We all make mistakes from following our lusts whatever those lusts might be.  The important thing is to realize your mistake, repent, and by doing so get closer to Allah.  The true jewels are only in paradise.   What looks like jewels in this worldly life is actually broken glass, which will hurt you if touch or wear them.